# ERROR: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Django_test"

Tags: postgresql

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and PostgreSQL latest version. I need to do the setup for my Django Project and so I have created a new database with username and a new password with the following command in my terminal

```
alter user postgres with password 'test123';
```

and for creating a new database :

```
create user Django_test with password 'test123';
```

But once I check with the connection in my database I am getting the error as mentioned in the Title.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql creates the user (role) in lower case.  Try to connect with user name django_test.

If you want the uppercase, do `create user "Django_test" with password 'test123'`.

Best regards,
Bjarni